# Conditional probability - 8 tosses of a coin

Tags: probability

We throw a coin 8 times. What is the probability of getting the same number of heads and tails, if on the last three tosses of a coin we got tails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting same number of heads and tails means getting $4$ heads and $4$ tails. You already got $3$ tails. So, the problem is reduced to getting $4$ heads and $1$ tail in the first five tosses. That is nothing but $5C_4$$*$$1\over 2^5$ $= $$5\over 32$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = $ the number of tails that remain, and $y = $ the total number of heads, then: $3+x = y, 3+x+y = 8$. Thus $ x = 1, y = 4$, Thus the remaining one tail can occur in any of the first $5$ tosses. So the probability is: $5\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^5$